# Flex 3 + Flash Player 10 FileReference save function

Tags: apache-flex, save, filereference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [help, losing extension when use FileReference download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243564/help-losing-extension-when-use-filereference-download)

Hi!

I'm having an issue that looks common when using the FileReference class in FP10 when saving a file.
The whole thing works fine as long as I don't change the default filename. If I do, then I loose the extension of the file... which is annoying >_<

I haven't found any "acceptable" workaround, but the posts I've seen are from a couple of months already. So I'm inquiring hoping that something's been done regarding this issue since then =)

Regards,
BS_C3

Comment: What are some of the old posts you've seen? What makes you think something has changed in the past couple of months?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243564/help-losing-extension-when-use-filereference-download

Comment: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=221737

Comment: so this is basically a dup on purpose?

Comment: Keep in mind that some operating systems might be hiding the file extension by default.

Comment: @Matt Chan - I've got that in mind, but hidden or not, it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i am aware of that you can do is: After succesfull saving check the filename and display a warning if the user used the wrong/no extension.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I saw this solution in other posts but it's not convincing for us. We do not want the user to have to put an extension... That's because the application is gonna be public and we'll most certainly have any kind of users... >_<